# ASP.NET PAGEMETHODS

Tags: asp.net-ajax

HI,

I want to create a fully AJAX enabled website i.e for every server call i m planning to use asp.net pagemethods. Is it fine if i use pagemethod for each & every to the server or there is an alternative for this?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to have a look at ASP.NET MVC. (you have access to your controllers directly with jQuery or your favorite javascript library)

It's a better aproach than using ASP.NET classic pagemethods.